# What is the scope of default keychain access group

Tags: ios, keychainitemwrapper

I am exploring `GenericKeyChain` project for iOS. In that there is a class `KeyChainItemWrapper` with `- (id)initWithIdentifier: (NSString *)identifier accessGroup:(NSString *) accessGroup;` method.

If I pass `nil` for `accessGroup` then it will consider Default Keychain Access Group. Now what will be the scope of my key chain item in case of default keychain access group. Will it be shared among whole system and all applications or it will be available only for my application only?

Any help will be thankful.